# Google Chart - Set Selection return the error

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I try to create a Combochart with Google and my chart contain the tooltips and
I create the close button for the tooltips. When a user clicks on the close button, the bellow function will be called:

```
function closeTooltipsHandler(row, col) {

    chartNewSelection = chart.getSelection();

    $.each(chartNewSelection, function(i){
        if(chartNewSelection[i].row == row && chartNewSelection[i].column == col) {
            chartNewSelection.splice(i,1);
            return false;
        }
    });

    chart.setSelection(chartNewSelection);
}
```

The function works fine :) But! This error is append in the console log when I "set selection" to my chart with new selection that remove some row:

[image: here]

Does anyone have any idea, how can I set the new selection for Google Chart with out this error?

Comment: Did you check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart)?

Comment: code seems fine, any other events on the chart? how is `closeTooltipsHandler` called?

Comment: @WhiteHat onclick='closeTooltipsHandler(0,11)' something like that.